# REACT NATIVE REDUX How to set an array in the reducer received by the action creator

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm currently trying to dispatch an array to my reducer, and set it in my state to use it on a component. It works fine with objects but I can't figure out how to do it with an array.

My action creator :

```
export const loadUserItems = () => {
  return async function(dispatch) {
    const url_current = 'https://whateverapi';
    const response = await axios.get(url_current);
    const items = response.data.items;
    dispatch(loadItems(items));
  }
}

function loadItems(data) {
  return {
    type: LOAD_USER_ITEMS,
    payload: data
  };
}
```

So if I get a single item in my array, it works perfectly fine.
I can set it to an object in my reducer and use it on my component.

My reducer :

```
import {
  LOAD_USER_ITEMS
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  items: []
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_USER_ITEMS :
      return {
        items: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

So here, action.payload is an array, I can console.log it and it outputs me the array. This array contains some JSON objects.

But when I try to access it in my component, it tells me it's undefined

```
import ... (no problems here)
class HomePage extends Component {
  loadUserItems() {
    this.props.loadUserItems();
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.loadUserItems();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
        <View style={styles.headerViewStyle}>
          <Image
            style={styles.headerImageStyle}
            source={require("../assets/images/header.png")}
          />
        </View>
          <View>
            <ItemSquareDisplay description={this.props.items[0].type}/>
          </View>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    items: state.items.items,
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {loadUserItems}) ( HomePage );
```

My array contains items, the first item.type is 'Fridge'...
But it tells me this.props.items[0].type is undefined.
I did the same but just dispatched the first item, and it worked fine, I could access this.props.items.type. But it doesn't seem to work if I send the entire array.

Need you one more time guys ! 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is you are accessing an empty array.

Initially your item array is an empty array inside the reducer. Now inside your component you call your action loadUserItems which will take a considerable time to fetch data and update the redux store. Within this time period your component's render method execute and try to access the 1st element of an empty array which will definitely give an error.

So what you could easily do is to check if array is not empty before accessing it's elements.

```
 <ItemSquareDisplay description={this.props.items && this.props.items.length > 0 ? this.props.items[0].type : ''} />
```

Please note that the reason to work when you use an object is that luckily the action has updated the redux store before the render method execute and access array.

Comment: I’m waiting for my train, try this in a few minutes.

Comment: Ok, it's done and it works. Thanks a lot for this mate, spend the last 4 hours trying to figure it out. I have to fix it everywhere in my code now.
Do you know another to await this behavior to escape checking every objects I get from the API ?

Comment: Actually this.props.items is used to check if an variable called item is defined. It's an additional check to avoid calling .length of an undefined array.

Answer (score 1):

Should use immutable variables in the reducer.

You can use `slice()` or `concat()`

In your case:

```
case LOAD_USER_ITEMS :
      return {
        items: action.payload.slice()
      };
```

or if you want to add more items on each load after

```
case LOAD_USER_ITEMS :
      return {
        items: state.items.concat(action.payload)
      };
```

make sure the payload is an array

Comment: Should I check if the item array exists ( see last answer ) with slice() in my component ? 
I'll have to add items in the array, so thanks for these methods.

Comment: In this case, slice will just create a copy of the array. You don't need to use it in the component (in the line from the previews answer).

Comment: You can use simply the spread operator.
return {
        items: [ ...state.items, ...action.payload ]
      };